# how to copy paste text from a file when using a modal dialogue in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using modal dialogue(ShowDialog) in my project and now, user want to copy and paste few text from other application  but modal dialogue will not allow them to do  the same because modal pop up doesn't allow to focus on other screen. I know I can use modeless dialogue but at this point I can't. Now my question is, are there any way to have focus on other screen using modal dialogue box?

```
 Dim f As New Form() 
 f.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Comment: No, use f.show(me) instead and it will remain on top.

Comment: `user want to copy and paste few text from other application... modal pop up doesn't allow to focus on other screen` no matter what method you use to show the form you should be able to focus another application. Did you mean another form in your application?

Comment: you are right @cruleD. but i cant use show(me) because ShowDialog will pause the execution and when we close the dialogue the execution starts form where it's being paused.

Comment: It's still not clear what screens are involved here. what screen does the user need to copy from? One in your app? Or one in a different app? If it's a different app, then you shouldn't be having any problems. If it's the same app, then using .Show instead of .ShowDialog, along with some other changes is going to be in order.

Comment: copying from one of my app not different app.

Comment: @adahero you can see how it's unclear what you're asking, right? You have given conflicting information. Please gather all your requirements and edit your question with them in a clear list.

Comment: This is a silly question. If you use a modal dialogue then you can't access other forms. That's the whole point. If you must use a moral dialogue then what you're asking for is joy possible by definition. You've been told what you need to do to be able to access other forms, i.e. don't use a modal dialogue. If that's not an option for another reason then you're out of luck. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: thanks @ jmcilhinney, what is that moral dialogue? how to use that?there are lot of code will execute after we close the dialogue box that is the reason at this point I can't use modeless dialogue box as you know the model dialogue box will pause the execution and the execution will continue when we close the dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

The Show function shows the form in a non modal form. This means that you can click on the parent form.

ShowDialog shows the form modally, meaning you cannot go to the parent form

Comment: is there a way using ShowDialog  we can copy some text from parent form?